# blank arrays getting from insights detail from FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have developed this piece of code and it is working good when I test it with my login id. when someone else login with its details it shows error (no data fetched through (FQL).
The code is :

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => "xxx",
  'secret' => "xxx",
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope'         => 'offline_access,email,manage_pages,read_insights'
            )
    );


$pid = $_GET['pageid'];
echo $pid;
echo "<br /><br />";

$total_fans = $facebook->api(
    "/".$pid."/insights/page_fans"
);

echo "This page has total " . $total_fans[data][0][values][0][value] . "likes (unique).";

echo "<br /><br />";

$fans_country = $facebook->api(
    "/".$pid."/insights/page_fans_country"
);
if(empty($fans_country)){
    echo "<p>No country specific data retrieved..</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Countryvise like counts :</p> ";
    foreach ($fans_country[data][0][values][0][value] as $key => $value) {
            echo "<span style='float: left; width: 50px; background: #DCDCDC;'> ". $key ."</span>
            <span style='float: left; width: 50px;'>" . $value ."</span>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

it works as, when I login with my FB account it will show pages in which my id is as admin and then for each page it will fetch total like counts and like counts countrywise.
for me it's OK but when anyone else logging with its account it return blank arrays.

thanks

Comment: I wonder where you loop through all pages... Other people would just see some info if they administer pages themselves.

Comment: And, by the way, offline_access permission is deprecated since a long time!

Comment: thanks tobi for your comments, basically I am looping in my index file where I fetch all pages admin by the user it works perfect and from there I pass page id as get variable to this page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're requesting an non-existing permission `"insights"`... The docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/insights/ say that

> A user or page access token with **read_insights** permission is required

To get a Page Access Token for the User's pages, use

```
GET /me/accounts
```

Comment: I am using :
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope'         => 'offline_access,email,manage_pages,read_insights'
            )
    );
Isn't it sufficient it or do I have to make some other call to get this permission.

Comment: offline_access is deprecated, and your sample code in your question shows "insights" (non-existing permission) instead of "read_insights"!

Comment: I am using read_insights now, could you please advise me how to get page access token while I have user access token while login and also I tried with my appId+|+my serect Id as token but no chance :(. Thanks for your kind efforts.

Comment: Please remove "offline_access" because it's no longer used! I edited my answer.

Comment: sorry @Tobi I was away, by using GET /me/accounts I could get the token but how can I get that with php on my webpage, also I have removed offline_access.

Comment: Man, you're already using $facebook->api() calls in your code...!